# Possibility to disable or hide CRON notification about starting one specific process

Tags: debian, cron, syslog

I was wondering if it is possible to having multiple cron jobs in crontab active, but only one of them starts each minute. The problem here is I wish to keep log of all others jobs informations with the exception of this only one.

```
Oct 25 14:50:01 dtest CRON[942]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python2.7 check.py > /dev/null 2>&1)
```

Currently I am getting flooded with all those lines, which made me curious if cron is able to supress a log entry for selected processes?

Comment: I don't think `cron` is designed to be configured to _not_ log event triggers for only one specific event.  You can either log, or not.  If you want to tail the log and eschew those entries, you can `tail -f logfile | grep -v 'python2\.7 check\.py'`.

Comment: Just was curious if there is actually any possibility to hide specific entry. Thank You for clarification

Comment: How are you being flooded? Email? Syslog? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

On distros using cronie (e.g. CentOS, RHEL, openSUSE, Fedora, Gentoo, Arch etc), you can just use the special "-" entry in the first column of crontab.

**Note that this doesn't help your situation, as you're on Debian, which uses Vixie cron**

Example usage, on CentOS, below.  See how the job to `touch /tmp/foo2` *did* get run at 19:37 but did not record the run in `/var/log/cron`.

```
# crontab -l
* * * * * touch /tmp/foo1
-* * * * * touch /tmp/foo2
# ls -l /tmp/foo*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct 25 19:37 /tmp/foo1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Oct 25 19:37 /tmp/foo2
# grep foo /var/log/cron
Oct 25 19:37:01 instance-2 CROND[12639]: (root) CMD (touch /tmp/foo1)
#
```

I'm not sure where this is fully documented, but the code establishing this behaviour can be seen in [cronie source code](https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie/blob/9c14c421f9e984d1d09af636a02fa2f2f13952d5/src/entry.c#L119-L138)

```
/* check for '-' as a first character, this option will disable 
* writing a syslog message about command getting executed
*/
if (ch == '-') {
/* if we are editing system crontab or user uid is 0 (root) 
* we are allowed to disable logging 
*/
    if (pw == NULL || pw->pw_uid == 0)
        e->flags |= DONT_LOG;
    else {
        log_it("CRON", getpid(), "ERROR", "Only privileged user can disable logging", 0);
        ecode = e_option;
        goto eof;
    }
    ch = get_char(file);
    if (ch == EOF) {
        free(e);
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Which is then referenced [elsewhere in the cronie source code](https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie/blob/730b23d8a741342fad62363a9d54eae6d75adbd8/src/do_command.c#L194-L199)

```
if ((e->flags & DONT_LOG) == 0) {
    char *x = mkprints((u_char *) e->cmd, strlen(e->cmd));
    log_it(usernm, getpid(), "CMD", x, 0);
    free(x);
}
```

Comment: The source code you referred is of "cronie", not "cron". The latter produces an error message: "bad minute".

Comment: @nst0022 - Yes, on reflection, Debian uses Vixie cron, which lacks this functionality.  Note added to answer.  Have left it present in case helps any non-Debian users when faced with this challenge.